# how to write images to a shared location for easy access?

Tags: java, android

The app I am working on uses the camera to take pictures and perform some processing on them. This is working with the following code:

```
private String getImageFolder() throws Exception {
    File mediaDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "my-app-folder");
    if (!mediaDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaDir.mkdirs()) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot create or find the image directory at " + mediaDir.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    return mediaDir.getPath();
}
```

The problem I have is that this stores it on a path like `/storage/0/simulated/android/data/com.myapp.codebase/Pictures/my-app-folder` and an essential part of this app is going to be that it is easy for users to copy the pictures taken from it over USB, so really I need it to be in a folder like `/Pictures/my-app-folder` - if I am honest I thought this was what `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` would do. I tried using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` but that just gave me a `FileNotFoundException` when I tried to use the path.

I have the following storage permissions enabled and checked at runtime:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What do I need to do in order to place my images on a consistent, easily accessible, file path?

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) but that just gave me a FileNotFoundException when I tried to use the path.
```

Then you forgot to put the right permissions in your manifest file.

And you are #1245 this year who forgot to ask for runtime permissions.

Google for them.

Comment: So it's not `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` that allows me to write external storage and read external storage? Both of those are enabled and I had naively assumed from their names that they would be the ones required if I wanted to write external storage or read external storage.

Comment: They are needed. And for Android 6+ you need to ask for permissions at runtime.

Comment: Sure, I didn't realise that part of the app was relevant because I thought if I could write to one part of the external storage that would mean I could write to other parts of the external storage. So given that I have both those permissions enabled both in the configuration _and_ at runtime, what further permissions do I need in order to get this working?

Comment: I already told you what you had to do. There is nothing more.

Comment: `both those permissions enabled both in the configuration and at runtime, `. ???? I do not understand what you mean with 'enabled at runtime'. Thats not the way one usually talks about obtaining them at runtime.

Comment: Alright, so I request the permissions when the application is running and then wait for the user grants them before I try to use them? I don't know if there is some other way people usually do that but it looks like a pretty standard mechanism. Perhaps I need to edit the question to include that part too. I was under the impression that "check the permissions before they are used" was how things tend to work in Android but I could be wrong, I'm new to the platform.